# Webm video playing video & audio in Movies & TV app but will only play video in windows media player and html?

Tags: html, audio, video, ffmpeg, webm

I have created a webm video file with transparency with ffmpeg out of a series of png files.  Then I add the audio track again in ffmpeg (I have tried both the opus and vorbis codecs).  When I play it in the Movies & TV app it plays just fine (audio and video).  In windows media player only the video plays.  In html (inside a video tag) the video will play if it is set to 'muted' but if it is not muted it doesn't play.

I am not sure what is going on.  Does anyone have any insights.  Do I need to run the audio from a seperate file?

Thanks,  Kate

Comment: OK I have done a lot more reading and it looks like the problem I am having is testing my page on Chrome.  Apparently they block autoplay.  Basically I am creating an education game so I need the audio to autoplay.  From what I have read after the user interacts with the page the audio should play.  I have put a button on the page for clicking but it doesn't seem to be working.  I will go see what I can find but if anyone can steer me toward a solution I would appreciate it.  Thanks,  K

Comment: Show your ffmpeg command and compete log.

Comment: Llogan, thanks but stumbled on a solution accidently after working on it a lot.  I play a transparent video clip and have the user unmute it.  After a page reload the video and attached audio play fine on "autoplay".  Just clicking a button (even when it changed something on the page - I think of that is "interacting" but apparently google doesn't) didn't allow "autoplay".  There is probably a more elegant way to accomplish this but I haven't found it.  I am pretty sure my ffmpeg is working fine.  It was just the snarl up with chrome.   Thanks,  K-